# adb devices DO see my phone however eclipse Android Device Chooser does NOT

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, sdk, adb

I'm working on Windows, SDK.
My device is Sony Ericsson xperia mini pro (SK17i).
I have it plugged in, USB debugging connected, etc.
I've already tried restarting phone as well PC,
And many other solutions,
but none of them worked for me.

As in topic `adb devices` display my device.
As well in eclipse LogCat I can see new entries when I do sth on device.
But when I run my project, list of devices in Android Device Chooser is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried restarting adb, on other PC, reinstalling device drivers, connecting to other USB ports, etc.

Comment: (yesterday everything was ok)

Comment: minSdk version number not  matching?

Comment: I am guessing this is resolved. If not, another problem might be that you have picked up a Target device manually previously.